# Scala function to get next letter of the alphabet

Tags: scala, string

Looking for something to do the following:

```
Given input: "s"
Expected output: "t"
```

Comment: What should it do when given "z"? Does case matter?

Comment: Are you giving it `Char`s or one-character `String`s?

Comment: Currently I have a String.  Given "z", it can return "{".  I'm using to setup byte range scans.

Comment: Have you tried to write it yourself?

Comment: I've included what I have below.  Seems there must be a better way.

Comment: IMHO, you should ask how to solve the actual problem you have instead of asking how to perform this minor step in what you think is the way to solve the problem.

Comment: good idea... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757678/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scala> def f(s: String) = (s.head + 1).toChar.toString
f: (s: String)java.lang.String

scala> f("s")
res10: java.lang.String = t
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def nextLetter(x:String) = (x(0) + 1).toChar.toString
```

Comment: You beat me by 46 sec. I wonder if perhaps charAt is slightly faster than head because its defined in java.lang.String?

Comment: You can make that even shorter by writing `(x(0) + 1).toChar.toString`.

Answer (score 2):

These methods return meaningful results only for letters:

```
def nextLetter(letter: Char): Option[Char] = {
  val validChars = ('a' to 'y') ++ ('A' to 'Y')
  if (validChars contains letter) Some((letter + 1).toChar) else None
}

def nextLetter(letter: String): Option[String] = {
  if (letter.length != 1) None
  else nextLetter(letter(0)).map(_.toString)
}

println(nextLetter('a'))
println(nextLetter('b'))
println(nextLetter('z'))
println(nextLetter('1'))
println(nextLetter('A'))
println(nextLetter("A"))
println(nextLetter("AB"))
```

Comment: I cannot make so tiny edit, but it should be '('a' to 'z') ++ ('A' to 'Z').

Comment: @kuki What is the next letter after 'Z'?

Comment: Oh, now I read what the initial question was. Sorry, you are right :)