# Create byte ranges for to match keys starting with a particular letter

Tags: scala

I'm doing HBase range scans, and I need to return all rows that begin with a particular letter.  Given a single letter as input, how do I create the correct startRow and endRow keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val letter = "s"
val startRow = letter
val endRow = (letter.charAt(0) + 1).toChar.toString
```